# Need help understanding whats being done here

Tags: f#

I am reading the book "F# for C# Developers" by Tao Liu. On page 139 There is an example of observer pattern. I am not sure if Microsoft press or Tao would allow me to post the full listing. But here is the portion I am trying to wrap my head around.

```
// subscribe to a notification function
member this.Subscribe notifyFunction = 
    let wrap f i = f i ; i
    notify <- wrap notifyFunction >> notify
```

specifically the `let wrap f i = f i; i`

I know that the semi-colon is a separator for next statement so `i` after semi-colon by being itself is indication of it being the return value of Subscribe

It looks like wrap is a function that takes f and i as arguments f being a function which accepts one argument and in the definition of wrap, f is invoked with i as argument.

In the next line wrap is supplied with one Composite function instead of two arguments.

Could someone help me understand this ? I looked it up in FSI and I saw the following

```
val wrap : f:('a -> unit) -> i:'a -> 'a
```

Which seems to me that `wrap` has two arguments one is `f` a function of a in which a is a type inferred from usage and returns nothing, the second argument to `wrap` is of type a itself which again is inferred from usage and wrap returns value of type a.

This whole combination of all is throwing me off. Could someone give me an easy way to understand this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis of `wrap` is correct: it just a way to push some side-effect into the identity-function (a bit of a *smell* IMHO)

I think a better way to understand this function could be:

```
let wrap (action : 'a -> unit) : 'a -> 'a =
   fun a -> action a
            a
```

The next line

```
notify <- wrap notifyFunction >> notify
```

is very strange - it's like `x = x + 1` - it changes the `notify` function (should be a mutable variable?) to call the `notifyFunction` before it will do whatever it did before.

Without seeing the rest of the code I can only speculate:
I guess `notify` starts with just beeing something like

```
let mutable notify = fun _ -> ()
```

Now whenever you first call `Subscripe` with an action `f: 'a -> ()` the code will change `notify` to be equivalent to this:

```
let notify a = 
   f a
   ()
```

A second call with `f'` will give you something equivalent to this:

```
let notify a = 
   f' a
   f a
   ()
```

and so on...

This will work but please: don't do something like this - it's unreadable and it's not at all the way you should handle things in F#

Comment: You got quite discerning skills. You got notify declaration exactly right

Comment: no need for much skills ... it's all in the types ;)

Comment: are you ok with the answer or is there something you don't understand?

Comment: Wrap could be used for logging every time the notification is fired or some such.  There are certainly cases where it shouldn't be done that way, but I don't think its inherently bad.

Comment: yes - but don't write it in a way where you cannot see what it is doing - in the example given here it is the "magic" function but the indent is hidden by bad naming and the lack of a type-signature (always give signatures for top-level and important functions) - it would have been clearer if warp here would use notifiyFunction directly and had name `prepend`or something - I will add my answer to make this a bit clearer